# Why does required textarea have an error border in Firefox before touch or focus?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, firefox, textarea

Textarea html element has a red border, as if input is invalid, on page load on Firefox. The state is valid as it is required, but should be activated only after being focused or touched.

`box-shadow:none;` will remove the border completely, but after touch or focus and invalid input the border should show.

Example: 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/controlled-text-area-required-xgshh?fontsize=14

Works as expected on Chrome and mobile browsers.